# extra slash after removing index.php using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am getting an extra slash after the domain name eg http://localhost/folder//project/list_all

Following is the htaccess code used to remove the index.php from the url
I am using codeigniter

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

It is after the above code an extra slash is added.

How can i sort it out?

```
//full code

controller/project

public function list_all() {
  //code....
)
//----------------------------

routes.php

$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
//--------------------------------

config.php
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/folder';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
//--------------------------------------------------

//controller home.php 
public function home() {
   //call model load data
   //call view
}
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$` will only impact a URL that starts with `/index.php/` , where is your .htaccess locared?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be some stuff twice, try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    # Send request via index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Your htaccess must be located where your index file is

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have put your code.. It still gives that double slashes

Comment: what should i put to fix it?

Comment: Then your problem is somewhere else. Do you have the reference to 'folder` in your $config[]  ?  If you can post some code where I can see how you are assembling this `url` maybe I can come to a solution.

Comment: I am also supposing that you have set  this to an empty value in your configuration  `$config['index_page'] = ' ' ;

Comment: yes, its $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/folder';                                     $config['index_page'] = '';                                                                                           $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';                                                         where can the error be..

Comment: How are you calling this controller in your $route[''] ?

Comment: have not put in the route its direct controller name and function name               . Have put default controller as $route['default_controller'] = 'home'; what can it be?

Comment: So you dont have a controller calling $route['project/list_all']  = "project/list_all", so try to add it to your route firts. I assume that you have created this controller already with this method in it.

Comment: nope.. tried. My home page is like http://localhost/folder / Is it bcs of the end slash that is coming ? how will i be able to remove it?

Comment: We are making a lot of guessing here and this discussion become to extended. I really need to see your code to solve this. If you post all the relevant code here I am willing to help you.

Comment: FWIW, this code won't "remove index.php" from the request, which appears to be one of the goals here.

Comment: @w3dk I still don't believe that the extra slash is the cause of that.

Comment: the code works only thing is that it creates an extra slash